# I don't know how to determine the P-value for my OR.

Tags: logistic, spss, binary-data, odds-ratio

I'm new to logistic regression.suppose i have a binary outcome (Y) and categorical independent variable (X). when i run the test on spss, for every category there is a different P value. please i want to know which one to consider and also i read in some article the term (P for trend) is it different from the P-value??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First take the time to read the article: [UCLA STATS: SPSS Annotated output for the logistic regression](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/output/logistic.htm).

There are two points here:

1. Test the overall significance of X (i.e., all categories)
2. Testing individuals levels of X against a default level of X

For (**1**), there should have been a table indicated the statistical significance of X. Is there a table `Variables in the Equation`? Look for the entry without a `Exp(B)` entry. In that row, `Sig.` is the overall significance of adding X to a Null model.

For (**2**), statistical programs will usually set one of the category levels 
of X as the default level for comparisons. Check which level SPSS is using. Then the other rows (e.g., X(1)) are the represents the difference between level 1 of X and the default level of X.

Drop the paper about 'P for trend', it's not what your looking for.

Comment: thank you very much! how about if the CI for one of the catogry was containing 1? although the over all X is significant. and we have to report the overall significance of X  right?